# How to do Add/Delete/Update QuickBooks REST API V2. ASP.NET WebForm?

Tags: asp.net, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

[Solved] It appears that the "Show As" field is a non-updatable field. When we use other fields, it works perfectly.

I just started to play with QB API V2 for QB Enterprise today. I am learning how to do add/update/view/delete operations with ASP.NET Webform. I downloaded the sample from QB here https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code

I can see my company list. Now I try to update a company field from the code below and it is not updating and not giving me any error. Can anyone see if I miss anything?

```
appToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationToken"];
realmId = HttpContext.Current.Session["realm"].ToString();
accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"].ToString();
accessTokenSecret = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString();
consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
dataSourcetype = HttpContext.Current.Session["dataSource"].ToString().ToLower() == "qbd" ? IntuitServicesType.QBD : IntuitServicesType.QBO;

OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator =  new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, appToken, realmId, dataSourcetype);
DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);

var qbdCustomerQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
qbdCustomerQuery.ItemElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemChoiceType4.StartPage;
qbdCustomerQuery.Item = "1";
qbdCustomerQuery.ChunkSize = "10";
var qbdCustomers = qbdCustomerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(context).ToList();
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer bb = qbdCustomers.FirstOrDefault();

bb.ShowAs = "TTTTT";
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer bbUpdate = commonService.Update(bb) as Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer;
```

I enabled the log and this is the request and the response.

Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Mod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="07e1d63eae654991aca3438ff787b6f4" FullResponse="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><ExternalRealmId>832118285</ExternalRealmId><Object xsi:type="Customer"><Id idDomain="QB">1</Id><SyncToken>3</SyncToken><MetaData><CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy><CreateTime>2013-11-05T19:03:18Z</CreateTime><LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy><LastUpdatedTime>2013-11-05T19:06:21Z</LastUpdatedTime></MetaData><ExternalKey>1001741590</ExternalKey><Synchronized>false</Synchronized><PartyReferenceId idDomain="QB">1</PartyReferenceId><TypeOf>Person</TypeOf><Name>Samurai</Name><Address><Id>2213595</Id><Line1>Samurai</Line1><Line2>Samu Rai</Line2><Default>true</Default><Tag>Billing</Tag></Address><Phone><Id>1317517</Id><DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType><FreeFormNumber>111-111-1111</FreeFormNumber><Default>true</Default><Tag>Business</Tag></Phone><Email><Id>603369</Id><Address>samu@gmail.com</Address><Default>true</Default><Tag>Business</Tag></Email><Title>Mr.</Title><GivenName>Samu</GivenName><FamilyName>Rai</FamilyName><DBAName>Samurai</DBAName><Active>true</Active><ShowAs>TTTTT</ShowAs><OpenBalance><CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode><Amount>0</Amount></OpenBalance><JobInfo><Status>None</Status></JobInfo></Object></Mod>
```

Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Success RequestId="07e1d63eae654991aca3438ff787b6f4"><Customer><Id idDomain="QB">1</Id><SyncToken>4</SyncToken><MetaData><CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy><CreateTime>2013-11-05T19:03:18Z</CreateTime><LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy><LastUpdatedTime>2013-11-05T19:11:33Z</LastUpdatedTime></MetaData><ExternalKey idDomain="NG">1001741590</ExternalKey><Synchronized>false</Synchronized><PartyReferenceId idDomain="QB">1</PartyReferenceId><TypeOf>Person</TypeOf><Name>Samurai</Name><Address><Id idDomain="NG">2213620</Id><Line1>Samurai</Line1><Line2>Samu Rai</Line2><Default>true</Default><Tag>Billing</Tag></Address><Phone><Id idDomain="NG">1317538</Id><DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType><FreeFormNumber>111-111-1111</FreeFormNumber><Default>true</Default><Tag>Business</Tag></Phone><Email><Id idDomain="NG">603372</Id><Address>samu@gmail.com</Address><Default>true</Default><Tag>Business</Tag></Email><Title>Mr.</Title><GivenName>Samu</GivenName><FamilyName>Rai</FamilyName><DBAName>Samurai</DBAName><Active>true</Active><ShowAs>Samurai</ShowAs><OpenBalance><CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode><Amount>0</Amount></OpenBalance><JobInfo><Status>None</Status></JobInfo></Customer><RequestName>CustomerMod</RequestName><ProcessedTime>2013-11-05T19:11:33Z</ProcessedTime></Success></RestResponse>
```

I see that it sent "TTTTT" for "Show As" field from the request, but the response shows the old value "Samurai"

I pasted request in API Explorer for QBD and below is the response. Not sure what the error means.

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Error RequestId="07e1d63eae654991aca3438ff787b6f4">
<RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
<ProcessedTime>2013-11-05T19:22:23.372Z</ProcessedTime>
<ErrorCode>-3002</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDesc>unique constraint (ESB.PTYAPI_IDX_RID) violated</ErrorDesc>
<DBErrorCode>00001</DBErrorCode>
```

Comment: Can you plz enable logging to debug this issue.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0600_logging

Please share the response XML. 

You can try these calls from APIExplorer.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO#Customer

Thanks